# Как опреобразовать str обратно в python list?

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь что-то сделать с ботом, работая при помощи [telepot](http://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Получаю данные:

```
a = bot.getUpdates()


print(type(a))
<class 'list'>
```

Содержимое:

```
print(a)

[{'update_id': 3344556677, 'message': {'message_id': 26, 'from': {'id': 3344556677, 'first_name': '31105', 'last_name': '63457', 'language_code': 'ru-RU'}, 'chat': {'id': 3344556677, 'first_name': '31105', 'last_name': '63457', 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1497291259, 'text': 'asd'}}]
```

Затем передаю эти данные себе во вьюху POST запросом, и принимаю так:

```
raw = request.body.decode('utf-8')
```

Вывожу тип:

```
print(type(raw))
<class 'str'>
```

При попытке получить обратно python obj:

```
payload = json.loads(raw)
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

Потому, что это не JSON.

Но как это правильно сделать ?

Comment: Может поможет замена всех одинарных кавычек в строке на двойные?

Comment: Я уже думал об этом. 
Вообще, в документации ясно написано : Bot API objects are represented as dictionary, но почему я вижу list ? 
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так перед тем как передавать, закодируйте в строку в формате json:

```
str_a = json.dumps(list_a)
```

И полученная строка потом великолепно распакуется с помощью `json.loads`

Comment: dumps возвращает строку, внутри ' ' , если так и передавать, то ругается на эти ковычки. Если отдавать без них, то всё нормально.

Comment: Единственное, за что я беспокоюсь, в каком виде данные будут приходить непосредственно от telegram во вьюху. 
Ведь это я сейчас их прежде чем отдать POSTом преобразовал в JSON, а как будет в реальной жизни?

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik, значит вы как-то неправильно дальше данные передаете, возможно еще к результату `dumps` применяете `repr`, этого делать не нужно.